# MySQL query optimization multiple join, pager

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.used,T2.used_count,(T3.ean IS NOT NULL) as isproduct
FROM (SELECT *,date(my_products.added) as addd
      FROM my_products WHERE uid = 4) T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(used) as used, SUM(used_count) AS used_count,ean
                 FROM my_products_status 
                 WHERE uid = 4 
                 GROUP BY ean) T2 ON T1.ean = T2.ean
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ean FROM products) T3 ON T1.ean = T3.ean WHERE uid = 4
ORDER BY ISNULL(name) ASC, name ASC
LIMIT 0,300`
```

How do I optimize this query? It seems that for about 15 000 products in `my_products` and about 60 000 products in `products`, for farther pages takes like 50 seconds... Indexes on `ean` in all tables.

The problem seems to be `T2` part... when I remove it, it works fine... but table in `T2` query contains only 100 rows... and T2 subquery execution time is 0.00s... so what the..? Maybe there is some problem with joining T1 with T2 when T2 has only few records that match T1 ... but same with T3, and T3 joins fine!

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 16384 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   100 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived4>         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 48123 |                                              |
|  4 | DERIVED     | products           | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 48123 | Using index                                  |
|  3 | DERIVED     | my_products_status | ALL   | uid           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   100 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | my_products        | ALL   | uid,uid_2     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 16384 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

my_products_status indexes:

```
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| my_products_status |          0 | uid      |            1 | uid         | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| my_products_status |          0 | uid      |            2 | device      | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| my_products_status |          0 | uid      |            3 | ean         | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| my_products_status |          1 | ean      |            1 | ean         | A         |         100 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

`explain SELECT MAX(used) as used, SUM(used_count) AS used_count,ean FROM my_products_status WHERE uid = 4 GROUP BY ean;`:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_products_status | ALL  | uid,uidean    | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  100 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

`explain SELECT *,date(my_products.added) as addd FROM my_products WHERE uid = 4;`:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_products | ALL  | uid,uid_2     | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 16384 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Start with using EXPLAIN …

Comment: Not sure what it Explains, but edited question...

Comment: You appear to lack at least one crucial index, `ean` is lacking, which means the GROUP BY `ean` is very slow

Comment: T2 subquery alone gives 100 records and it does it in 0.00 seconds... it has `ean` index but it is not primary key, as unique is (ean,uid)... edited question to show indexes... it seems that there is some problem with T1 <-> T2 join...

Comment: Do EXPLAIN on ``SELECT MAX(used) as used, SUM(used_count) AS used_count,ean
                 FROM my_products_status 
                 WHERE uid = 4 
                 GROUP BY ean``, if it shows no key in use, your key s aren't any good. Try to add a key that takes ``uid`` and ``ean``

Comment: @nrathaus I've added uid,ean key and still nothing... EXPLAIN shows possible keys: uid, uidean ...

Comment: Can you give the explain of the subquery: SELECT MAX(used) as used, SUM(used_count) AS used_count,ean
                 FROM my_products_status 
                 WHERE uid = 4 
                 GROUP BY ean ?

Comment: @nrathaus edited, added... please note that `my_products_status` has only 100 rows, and if I remove grouping from it it doesn't change a thing... but when I remove whole T2 subquery, everything works perfectly fine...

Comment: No... it's not true... when removing T2, it still works slow...

Comment: And EXPLAIN for SELECT *,date(my_products.added) as addd
      FROM my_products WHERE uid = 4 ?

Comment: @nrathaus edited... but seems that maybe not T2 is a problem but generally join... `SELECT T1.*,(T3.ean IS NOT NULL) as isproduct FROM (SELECT *,date(my_products.added) as addd FROM my_products WHERE uid = 4) T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT ean FROM products) T3 ON T1.ean = T3.ean WHERE uid = 4  ORDER BY ISNULL(name) ASC, name ASC LIMIT 0,300;`
300 rows in set (37.44 sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ean FROM products) T3 ON T1.ean = T3.ean
```

To this:

```
LEFT JOIN products T3 ON T1.ean = T3.ean
```

Comment: This actually works! Thank you! You saved the day :D I wonder how it will work when T2 table will be full...